# Create empty has_one association if preload is nil for ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have a User schema generated with phx.gen.auth, and to add stripe_details I have created a new StripeProfile struct such that `User has_one StripeProfile` and `StripeProfile belongs_to User`. I am building the association on user creation. The problem is I have existing users on my system who does not have the correct associations.

How do I create StripeProfile for existing Users ? Do I have to add the code in the migration file itself ?

Comment: hm, can you paste your code example? In general you will create `StripeProfile` by passing `user_id` over `put_change(:user_id, user.user_id)` if your `belongs_to` is setup-ed correctly.

Comment: In general, yes, I'd create things for existing data during migration; however, how would you know what to put for the data? (Then again, I have the same question about doing it during user creation too, so...)